# Group Array by multiple objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array, I have to group the values by month year and type and return total of `leavecount` field,

also if array item `holidayWork` has value then create a new type: `WOH`.

My Array:

```
[
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-01-01T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-02-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-02-04T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Feb"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 0.5,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-02-05T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Earned Leave",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "EL",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Feb"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-03-06T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Mar"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 0.5,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-04-07T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-04-10T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-04-11T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 0.5,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-05-12T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Casual/Sick Leave",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "CL",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "May"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 1,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-05-12T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "May"
    }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    {
        "Jan 2021" : [
            {
                "WFH" : 2
            }
        ],
        "Feb 2021" : [
            {
                "WFH" : 1
            },
            {
                "EL" : 0.5
            }
        ],
        "Mar 2021" : [
            {
                "WFH" : 1
            }
        ],
        "Apr 2021" : [
            {
                "WFH" : 2.5
            }
        ],
        "May 2021" : [
            {
                "WFH" : 0.5
            },
            {
                "WOH" : 0.5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried this code:

```
 let results = leaves.reduce(function (r, a) {
          r[a.mon+' '+a.vchYear] = r[a.mon+' '+a.vchYear] || [];
          r[a.vchYear][a.mon][a.vchLeaveTypeAlias].push(a)
          return r;
      }, Object.create(null));
```

Please help .....................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I have trouble understanding your expected result. Why does **May 2021** have **WFH** property where it should have **CL** property. Also why is **WOH** property of **May 2021** is `0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this is what you need (with some output corrections):

```js
const leaves = [
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-01-01T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-02-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-02-04T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Feb"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 0.5,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-02-05T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Earned Leave",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "EL",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Feb"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-03-06T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Mar"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 0.5,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-04-07T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-04-10T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-04-11T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Work From Home",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "WFH",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 0.5,
        "holidayWork": 0,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-05-12T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "Casual/Sick Leave",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "CL",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "May"
    },
    {
        "leavecount": 1,
        "holidayWork": 1,
        "dtAttendance": "2021-05-12T18:30:00.000Z",
        "vchLeaveTypeName": "",
        "vchLeaveTypeAlias": "",
        "Year": "2021",
        "mon": "May"
    }
];

let results = leaves.reduce(function (r, a) {
  const dateKey = `${a.mon} ${a.Year}`;
  r[dateKey] ??= [];

  let type;
  if (a.holidayWork !== 0) type = 'WOH';
  else type = a.vchLeaveTypeAlias;

  let typeEntry = r[dateKey].find(entry => entry[type] !== undefined);
  if (!typeEntry) {
    typeEntry = { [type]: 0 };
    r[dateKey].push(typeEntry);
  }

  typeEntry[type] += a.leavecount;
  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(results);
```